# How can I tell the compiler a Java function must be called if overridden?

Tags: java, android

In Android there's a pretty standard method for making your system classes interact with theirs:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume ();
    //your code here
}
```

When you type "onr" and then control-space in eclipse, the  stub fills out like this, with the super method in the call. how would you indicate that you want to do this from the 
superclass?

Comment: What do you mean by "from the superclass"?

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking - are you asking if their is a way to ensure that the refined onResume is called (i.e. create an error if it isn't?)

Comment: To do what from the superclass?

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases for calling a function in a subclass from the superclass:

- **When the superclass or one of its ancestors has declared the function that you want to call**  - simply call that function: the override is going to be called.
- **When the function is first introduced in a subclass** - you need an explicit cast in your call. This option almost always indicates a problem in your design, and should be avoided.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in the slightest.

Comment: @EJP I would be really curious to learn how an answer that tells the OP how to call a subclass method from the superclass does not answer ("in the slightest", no less) the question about calling subclass methods from superclass.

Answer (score 0):

when implementing subclassing, you can override any public or protected method, the default behavior of a overridden method in Eclipse is to do what the parent class does, therefor the automatic code for any method that's overriden is to call the parent via `super`.

Comment: Very misleading. That's only the 'default' if you use the Eclipse short-cut key described in the question. Nothing to do with Java (or programming at all).

Comment: in theory, the default behavior of calling a parent class method from a child class is to run the parent method

Comment: In theory and in practice. What else could it possibly do? It's irrelevant. The default behaviour for a overridden method *in Eclipse* is to to call the superclass method *if you use that shortcut*. The missing word from your answer and your comment is 'Eclipse'. You've written it all as though this was how Java behaves. It isn't.